# Magento 2 - discount depend on Payment Method does not work

Tags: magento2, discount

I go to Magento 2 *Admin > Marketing > Promotions > Cart Price Rules* and create a new Rule: Bank Transfer Payment:

Tab Rule Information:

- Rule Name: Bank Transfer Payment
- Status: Active
- Websites: Main Website
- Customer Groups: select all
- Coupon: No Coupon
- Uses per Customer: 0
- From: blank
- To: blank
- Priority: 0
- Public in RSS Feed: No

Conditions tab:

- If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

  - Payment Method  is  Bank Transfer Payment

Actions Tab:

- Apply: percent of product price discount
- Discount Amount: 2
- Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0
- Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0
- Apply to Shipping Amount: No
- Discard subsequent rules: No
- Free Shipping: No
- Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items): nothing

Then I enable Bank Transfer Payment method, go to checkout page, click on Bank Transfer Payment but the Discount Percent Price does not show up in Order Summary.

[image]

Please give me an advice. How can make a discount on payment method on Magento 2. For Magento 1, it wroks well.

Thanks very much

Comment: You can post your rule here?

Comment: I posted my Rule. Can you check for me please?

Comment: Try to add the activated date of the rule?

Comment: I try to add the start Date of the rule but still nothing happen in Order Summary when click on Bank Transfer Payment option

Comment: It may be a Magento bug. You can post your issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: Thanks. I posted the issue here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5937

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This rule doesn't work because Magento 2 doesn't save payment method to quote when you select one. And it also doesn't reload totals when selecting a payment method. And unfortunately, you have to write a custom module to solve the issue.

The new module needs only 4 files to be created:

1. **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
       <router id="standard">
           <route id="namespace_modulename" frontName="namespace_modulename">
               <module name="Namespace_ModuleName"/>
           </route>
       </router>
   </config>
   ```

   This will define a new controller for our module.
2. **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Controller/Checkout/ApplyPaymentMethod.php**

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Controller\Checkout;

   class ApplyPaymentMethod extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
   {
       /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
        */
       protected $resultForwardFactory;

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory
        */
       protected $layoutFactory;

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
        */
       protected $cart;

       /**
        * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
        * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
        */
       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
           \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
           \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
           \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
       ) {
           $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
           $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
           $this->cart = $cart;

           parent::__construct($context);
       }

       /**
        * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
        */
       public function execute()
       {
           $pMethod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('payment_method');

           $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();

           $quote->getPayment()->setMethod($pMethod['method']);

           $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
           $quote->collectTotals();
           $quote->save();
       }
   }
   ```

   This file creates controller action to save the selected payment method to quote
3. **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

   ```
   var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method':
                   'Namespace_ModuleName/js/action/select-payment-method'
           }
       }
   };
   ```

   This file allows to override `Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method` file
4. **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js**

   ```
   define(
       [
           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
           'jquery',
           'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
       ],
       function (quote, fullScreenLoader, jQuery, getTotalsAction) {
           'use strict';
           return function (paymentMethod) {
               quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);

               fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

               jQuery.ajax('/namespace_modulename/checkout/applyPaymentMethod', {
                   data: {payment_method: paymentMethod},
                   complete: function () {
                       getTotalsAction([]);
                       fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                   }
               });

           }
       }
   );
   ```

   Sends ajax request to save payment method and reload cart totals.

**P.S.** Parts of the code were taken from [Payment Fee](https://www.magestyapps.com/magento-2-extensions/payment-fees-m2.html) extension for Magento 2.

Comment: Thanks very much MagestyApps, I created a new Module follow your instruction. However, at the end I got this problem         
jquery.js http://192.168.41.59/phoenix_checkout/checkout/applyPaymentMethod 404 (Not Found).   Did you get this bug before?

Comment: It works really well. Thanks MagestyApps very much. This solution is perfect.

Comment: It works, You saved my time. Thank You :)

Comment: Awesome stuff, thx. The Cart price rule for payment methods was removed btw (https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb65d05d41f30cd6a10fdfffb10b1dd8f42d3a77#diff-6af1fa68376d90ae611de38779431624). I added the line "'payment_method' => __('Payment Method')," again, now I can create cart price rules for payment methods.

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks. +1 :)

Comment: Thanks you save my time +1

Comment: Great.. You made my day +1

Answer (score 3):

On Magento 2.2 i couldn't get MagestyApps answer to work. I needed to add some additional files. Because:

- Cart Price Rule for Payment Method [was removed](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb65d05d41f30cd6a10fdfffb10b1dd8f42d3a77#diff-6af1fa68376d90ae611de38779431624) from admin (as pointed out by DaFunkyAlex);
- In Magento 2.2 the discount was not being applied on the quote, because the method `\Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\FilterTextGenerator\Address\PaymentMethod::generateFilterText` (actually it falls back to `\Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\FilterTextGenerator\Address::generateFilterText`), was expecting the data `payment_method` to be set on the quote addresses;
- Even changing the controller from MagestyApps answer to set `payment_method` data on the quote addresses, didn't work when the quote became an order, because it don't persist `payment_method`;

The following module worked out for me (thanks to MagestyApps answer, it was based on top of that):

**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_SalesRulesPaymentMethod',
    __DIR__
);
```

**etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_SalesRulesPaymentMethod" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_AdvancedSalesRule"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_SalesRules"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\FilterTextGenerator\Address\PaymentMethod"
                type="Vendor\SalesRulesPaymentMethod\Model\Rule\Condition\FilterTextGenerator\Address\PaymentMethod"/>
    <type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address">
        <plugin name="addPaymentMethodOptionBack" type="Vendor\SalesRulesPaymentMethod\Plugin\AddPaymentMethodOptionBack" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="salesrulespaymentmethod" frontName="salesrulespaymentmethod">
            <module name="Vendor_SalesRulesPaymentMethod"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**Controller/Checkout/ApplyPaymentMethod.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesRulesPaymentMethod\Controller\Checkout;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;

class ApplyPaymentMethod extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @var LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $layoutFactory;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param LayoutFactory $layoutFactory
     * @param ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        Cart $cart
    ) {
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return ResponseInterface|ResultInterface|void
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $pMethod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('payment_method');

        /** @var Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->cart->getQuote();

        $quote->getPayment()->setMethod($pMethod['method']);

        $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
        $quote->collectTotals();

        $quote->save();
    }
}
```

**Model/Rule/Condition/FilterTextGenerator/Address/PaymentMethod.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesRulesPaymentMethod\Model\Rule\Condition\FilterTextGenerator\Address;

use Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\FilterTextGenerator\Address\PaymentMethod as BasePaymentMethod;

class PaymentMethod extends BasePaymentMethod
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $quoteAddress
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function generateFilterText(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $quoteAddress)
    {
        $filterText = [];
        if ($quoteAddress instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address) {
            $value = $quoteAddress->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
            if (is_scalar($value)) {
                $filterText[] = $this->getFilterTextPrefix() . $this->attribute . ':' . $value;
            }
        }

        return $filterText;
    }
}
```

**Plugin/AddPaymentMethodOptionBack.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\SalesRulesPaymentMethod\Plugin;

use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address;

class AddPaymentMethodOptionBack
{
    /**
     * @param Address $subject
     * @param $result
     * @return Address
     */
    public function afterLoadAttributeOptions(Address $subject, $result)
    {
        $attributeOption = $subject->getAttributeOption();
        $attributeOption['payment_method'] = __('Payment Method');

        $subject->setAttributeOption($attributeOption);

        return $subject;
    }
}
```

**view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method':
                'Vendor_SalesRulesPaymentMethod/js/action/select-payment-method'
        }
    }
};
```

**view/frontend/web/js/action/select-payment-method.js**

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    ],
    function (quote, fullScreenLoader, jQuery, getTotalsAction) {
        'use strict';
        return function (paymentMethod) {
            quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);

            fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

            jQuery.ajax('/salesrulespaymentmethod/checkout/applyPaymentMethod', {
                data: {payment_method: paymentMethod},
                complete: function () {
                    getTotalsAction([]);
                    fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                }
            });

        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I get this when trying to compile: `Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address\PaymentMethod' not found in Vendor/SalesRulesPaymentMethod/Model/Rule/Condition/FilterTextGenerator/Address/PaymentMethod.php on line 7`. I even tried to change AdvancedSalesRule to SalesRule as I can see there is no AdvancedSalesRule  Model in Magento 2.2.2

Comment: for magento 2.1.9, should we omit AdvancedSalesRule parts?

Comment: Getting error  when compile: Fatal error: Class 'Magento\AdvancedSalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Address\PaymentMethod' not found in Vendor/SalesRulesPaymentMethod/Model/Rule/Condition/FilterTextGenerator/Address/PaymentMethod.php on line 7

Comment: AdvancedSalesRule is not available in Magento 2.1.5

Answer (score 2):

We just checked the same rule and found that it doesn't work. Using the same conditions, no information about selected chosen method is sent and it is not recorded anywhere until the order is placed and the rule may not work.

[image]

Address has no payment method until validation and it gets the payment method from payment quote that doesn't exist because no information has been sent (`$model->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod()` returns `null`).

[image]

We suppose, that this is Magento bug. When you choose a payment method the information should be sent in advance.

Comment: The answer from MagestyApps  is accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with the custom module is working.

I just thought that it would be useful info for Magento beginners to know that you also need to add these files to be able to add and enable this module:

(copy from a different module and change files according to your module name and namespace)

```
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/composer.js
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/registration.php
app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/etc/module.xml
```

then you would be able to run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

i created the files and replaced the Namespaces and modulename but i think my files wont be executed.

Maybe an error on my files??

**registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(
ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Jacor_Checkoutpayment',
__DIR__
);
```

**composer.json**

```
{
"name": "jacor/checkoutpayment",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Jacor\\Checkoutpayment\\": ""
    },
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
}
```

}

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Jacor_Checkoutpayment" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually, overriding of magento core files is not a good idea. Instead of override `Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method` better create a mixin for it. And you can deale it without creating a new controller.
See below (in addition to @magestyapps answer)

1. **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

   ```
       var config = {
           config: {
               mixins: {
                   'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method': {
                       'Namespace_ModuleName/js/checkout/action/select-payment-method-mixin': true
                   },
               }
           }
       };
   ```
2. **app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/js/checkout/action/select-payment-method-mixin.js**

   ```
       define([
       'jquery',
       'mage/utils/wrapper',
       'mage/storage',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
       'Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder',
       'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
   ], function ($, wrapper, storage, getTotalsAction, fullScreenLoader, quote, urlBuilder, customer) {
       'use strict';
       return function (selectPaymentMethod) {
           return wrapper.wrap(selectPaymentMethod, function (originalAction, paymentMethod) {
               var serviceUrl, payload;

               originalAction(paymentMethod);

               payload = {
                   method: paymentMethod
               };
               if (customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                   serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/selected-payment-method', {});
               } else {
                   serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/guest-carts/:cartId/selected-payment-method', {
                       cartId: quote.getQuoteId()
                   });
               }
               fullScreenLoader.startLoader();
               storage.put(
                   serviceUrl,
                   JSON.stringify(payload)
               ).success(function () {
                   getTotalsAction([]);
                   fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
               });
           });
       };
   });
   ```