# Magento 2 Payment methods reload on Checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

The task is to make some restrictions on payment method, but only after they are loaded on checkout page.
User select one of payment methods and after that I need to do some logic and if it return false show message to user and hide this method.

I have overried *Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method* like here [Magento 2 - discount depend on Payment Method does not work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128580/magento-2-discount-depend-on-payment-method-does-not-work) but don't know what to do next?

Comment: Need to use Observer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/137738/magento-2-how-to-show-hide-payment-method-on-basis-of-amount

Comment: I use observer for event 'payment_method_is_active'. And there I use $result->setData('is_available', false); to disable method. But how to fire this event again, after the payment method was selected on checkout page?