# All payment methods are not coming in Cart Price Rule

Tags: payment-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.3.1

In Magento 2.3.1 I'm creating Cart Price Rule for Payment Methods. I have to create for Bank Transfer but there is Bank Transfer option not coming.

https://www.screencast.com/t/h4rc4PnQU

Answer (score 12, accepted):

open file 
vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/data.php

at line number 268 
put this line

```
$data['active'] = 1;
```

if you dont want to change in the core file than you need to override that file 
follow the below code

Go to Vendor/Extension/etc/di.xml And Write below code into di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Payment\Helper\Data" type="Vendor\Extension\Helper\Data"/>
</config>
```

Next Step is to Create Data.php file at Vendor\Extension\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Helper;

use Magento\Payment\Helper\Data as MainHelper;

class Data extends MainHelper
{
    public function getPaymentMethodList($sorted = true, $asLabelValue = false, $withGroups = false, $store = null)
    {
        $methods = [];
        $groups = [];
        $groupRelations = [];


        foreach ($this->getPaymentMethods() as $code => $data) {

            $data['active'] = 1;

            if (!empty($data['active'])) {
                $storedTitle = $this->getMethodInstance($code)->getConfigData('title', $store);
                if (isset($storedTitle)) {
                    $methods[$code] = $storedTitle;
                } elseif (isset($data['title'])) {
                    $methods[$code] = $data['title'];
                }
            }
            if ($asLabelValue && $withGroups && isset($data['group'])) {
                $groupRelations[$code] = $data['group'];
            }
        }
        if ($asLabelValue && $withGroups) {
            $groups = $this->_paymentConfig->getGroups();
            foreach ($groups as $code => $title) {
                $methods[$code] = $title;
            }
        }
        if ($sorted) {
            asort($methods);
        }
        if ($asLabelValue) {
            $labelValues = [];
            foreach ($methods as $code => $title) {
                $labelValues[$code] = [];
            }
            foreach ($methods as $code => $title) {
                if (isset($groups[$code])) {
                    $labelValues[$code]['label'] = $title;
                    if (!isset($labelValues[$code]['value'])) {
                        $labelValues[$code]['value'] = null;
                    }
                } elseif (isset($groupRelations[$code])) {
                    unset($labelValues[$code]);
                    $labelValues[$groupRelations[$code]]['value'][$code] = ['value' => $code, 'label' => $title];
                } else {
                    $labelValues[$code] = ['value' => $code, 'label' => $title];
                }
            }

            return $labelValues;
        }


        return $methods;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working and i can't edit core files.

Comment: In Magento 2.3.1 we can create rule using Payment method, but why all the payment methods are not coming there in condition selection?

Comment: its working for me can you share the screenshot what you place exact,
if you dont want to edit core file than you override that file and change

Comment: https://meetanshi.d.pr/ynAITh

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/0ydCNELqiLs

Comment: put that line after foreach ($this->getPaymentMethods() as $code => $data) {

you put line at wrong place

Comment: https://meetanshi.d.pr/VTKeZw

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95057/discussion-between-jigs-parmar-and-magecode).

Comment: drops.meetanshi.com/VTKeZw

Comment: drops.meetanshi.com/ynAITh

Comment: drops.meetanshi.com/VTKeZw

Answer (score 5):

You can use below link

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128606/70565

I hope it's usefully for you.

Comment: In Magento 2.3.1 we can create rule using Payment method, but why all the payment methods are not coming there in condition selection?

Comment: I have check in magento 231 version, in that payment method condition is not available.

Comment: Are you using any extension or default magento functionality?

Comment: Default Magento functionality

Comment: I have check in default magento 231 version, in that payment method condition is not available.