# AMT set in paypal API

Tags: magento2, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to change the AMT that is passed to Paypal. My actual issue is that the AMT passed to Paypal API includes my flat rate shipping of 10 which needs to be removed as I have set free shipping for > 25 & 10 flatrate for < 25.

I want to check from where AMT is set in Paypal with Shipping amount so I can set condition of > 25.

Currently, cart page & all are showing perfect amount except the paypal API

Answer (score 0):

In magento PayPal settings have you set the following option to yes.

> Transfer shipping options

This option enables the user to facilitate with various shipping options for the product delivery

If that doesn't work are you able to add more detail on how you have configured your free shipping.

I was doing some additional reading and something doesn't seem right with payment extensions recognising discounts. Is the issue you have described something like this?

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5937

Which leads me to this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/128606/70343

Comment: I have set freen shipping via 'Minimum Order Amount' > 25

Comment: Yep so standard stuff then. Did you see that second link?